# getting error - Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.while editing status column whose data type is bit

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

while editing the status column grid view  im getting this error - Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.i have newly added one column status(bit,null)  in table so status column having null value. while binding status column with NULL value getting error .

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="status">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "status") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEditStatus" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("status")) %>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAddStatus" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("status")) %>' />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

how to edit edititem template so that this error will not come while editing grid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are trying to convert a DBNull to Boolean, you need to check this while retrieving the data and calculate accordingly while fetching it from DB:-

```
bool status = reader["status"] is DBNull ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(reader["status"]);
```

Comment: @krishnamohan - Hey were you able to solve it? By reader I meant while fetching your data by SqlDataReader.